# a thick curve in TikZ with squares at endpoints

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to draw in TikZ say a thick cubic spline with short, roughly squarish segments of the curve at the ends in a different color?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an arrow at the rectangular end.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1ex,gray!50, {Butt Cap[black]}-{Butt Cap[black]}] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,-1) .. (3,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cap]